# Minimum-Waste Print Job Grouping Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, printing, grouping

I work at a publishing house and I am setting up one of our presses for "ganging", in other words, printing multiple jobs simultaneously.  Given that different print jobs can have different quantities, and anywhere from 1 to 20 jobs might need to be considered at a time, the problem would be to determine which jobs to group together to minimize waste (waste coming from over-printing on smaller-quantity jobs in a given set, that is).

Given the following stable data:

1. All jobs are equal in terms of spatial size--placement on paper doesn't come into consideration.
2. There are three "lanes", meaning that three jobs can be printed simultaneously.
3. Ideally, each lane has one job.  Part of the problem is minimizing how many lanes each job is run on.
4. If necessary, one job could be run on two lanes, with a second job on the third lane.
5. The "grouping" waste from a given set of jobs (let's say the quantities of them are x, y and z) would be the highest number minus the two lower numbers.  So if x is the higher number, the grouping waste would be (x - y) + (x - z).  Otherwise stated, waste is produced by printing job Y and Z (in excess of their quantities) up to the quantity of X.  The grouping waste would be a qualifier for the given set, meaning it could not exceed a certain quantity or the job would simply be printed alone.

So the question is stated: how to determine which sets of jobs are grouped together, out of any given number of jobs, based on the qualifiers of 1) Three similar quantities OR 2) Two quantities where one is approximately double the other, AND with the aim of minimal total grouping waste across the various sets.

(Edit) Quantity Information:
Typical job quantities can be from 150 to 350 on foreign languages, or 500 to 1000 on English print runs.  This data can be used to set up some scenarios for an algorithm.  For example, let's say you had 5 jobs:

1000, 500, 500, 450, 250

By looking at it, I can see a couple of answers.  Obviously (1000/500/500) is not efficient as you'll have a grouping waste of 1000.  (500/500/450) is better as you'll have a waste of 50, but then you run (1000) and (250) alone.  But you could also run (1000/500) with 1000 on two lanes, (500/250) with 500 on two lanes and then (450) alone.

In terms of trade-offs for lane minimization vs. wastage, we could say that any grouping waste over 200 is excessive.

(End Edit)

...Needless to say, quite a problem.  (For me.)

I am a moderately skilled programmer but I do not have much familiarity with algorithms and I am not fully studied in the mathematics of the area.  I'm I/P writing a sort of brute-force program that simply tries all options, neglecting any option tree that seems to have excessive grouping waste.  However, I can't help but hope there's an easier and more efficient method.

I've looked at various websites trying to find out more about algorithms in general and have been slogging my way through the symbology, but it's slow going.  Unfortunately, Wikipedia's articles on the subject are very cross-dependent and it's difficult to find an "in".  The only thing I've been able to really find would seem to be a definition of the rough type of algorithm I need: "Exclusive Distance Clustering", one-dimensionally speaking.

I did look at what seems to be the popularly referred-to algorithm on this site, the Bin Packing one, but I was unable to see exactly how it would work with my problem.

Comment: You should probably add the tag "algorithms".

Comment: Would whoever voted to close as off topic like to explain why?

Comment: How do you value minimising waste against minimising the number of lanes used? If you could save one unit by splitting a job over two lanes rather than one, would you want to do it? What if you could save ten units? Where is the cutoff?

Comment: Can you overlap jobs? If you have two three-unit jobs and six two-unit jobs, can you run the three-unit jobs sequentially on lane A, three two-unit jobs on B, and three two-unit jobs on C, taking six units of printing time in total?

Comment: @tom anderson For overlapping jobs: that is theoretically possible for me to do, but the printing system is not currently set up for it.  If you have an idea on how that would work for the calculations, I would be interested, because if it seems workable I might be persuaded to completely rehaul the printing system.

I will edit my Question to include information on quantities, to answer your question on lane/wastage cutoffs.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial for bin-packing: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5540/bin-packing/. I've used it for myself.

Comment: Why can't you just split every job to three equal sized parts (e.g. 1000 = 333 + 333 + 334) and always run only one job at a time, and through all the three lines?

Comment: @Matt Mc I can answer that question re overlapping jobs! This is actually *not* the bin-packing problem, because the number of "bins" is fixed. Rather, it's the offline makespan minimisation problem (which seems to be exactly the same as the multiprocessor scheduling problem - note that in the article on the latter on Wikipedia, the word "overlap" is used with a different meaning). The good news is that, as I recently wrote on Wikipedia, the offline makespan minimisation problem has an approximation algorithm which runs in polynomial time (I cited the relevant paper in the Wikipedia article).

Answer (score 2):

This seems similar to the classic Operations Research 'cutting stock' problem. For the formal mathematical treatment try
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

I've coded solutions for the cutting stock problems using delayed column generation technique from  the paper "Selection and Design of Heuristic Procedures for Solving Roll Trim Problems" by Robert W. Haessler (Management Sci. Dec '88). I tested it up to a hundred rolls without problem. Understanding how to get the residuals from the first iteration, and using them to craft the new equation for the next iteration is quite interesting. See if you can get hold of this paper, as the author discusses variations closer to your problem.

If you get to a technique that's workable I recommend using a capable linear algebra solver, rather than re-inventing the wheel. Whilst simplex method is easy enough to code yourself for fractional solutions, what you are dealing with here is harder - it's a mixed integer problem. For a modern C mixed integer solver (MIP) using eg. branch & bound, with Java/python bindings I recommend [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/).

When I wrote this I found [this NEOS guide page](http://www.neos-guide.org/CaseStudies/cutting/index.html) useful. Online solver looks defunct through (for me it returns perl code rather than executing it). There's still some  background information.

Edit - a few notes: I'll summarise the differences between your problem and that of the cutting stock:
1) cutting stock has input lengths that are indivisible. You can simulate your divisible problems by running the problem multiple times, breaking up the jobs into 1.0, {0.5, 0.5} time original lengths.
2) your 'length of print run' map to the section length
3) choose a large stock length

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try and attack the "ideal" case, in which no jobs are split between lanes or printed alone.

Let n be the number of jobs, rounded up to the nearest multiple of 3. Dummy zero-length jobs can be created to make the number of jobs a multiple of 3.

If n=3, this is trivial, because there's only one possible solution. So assume n>3.

The job (or one of the jobs if there are several) with the highest quantity must inevitably be the highest or joint-highest of the longest job group (or one of the joint longest job groups if there is a tie). Equal-quantity jobs are interchangeable, so just pick one and call that the highest if there is a tie.

So if n=6, you have two job groups, of which the longest-or-equal one has a fixed highest or joint-highest quantity job. So the only question is how to arrange the other 5 jobs between the groups. The formula for calculating the grouping waste can be expressed as 2∑h<sub>i</sub> - ∑x<sub>j</sub> where the h<sub>i</sub>s are the highest quantities in each group and the x<sub>j</sub>s are the other quantities. So moving from one possible solution to another is going to involve swapping one of the h's with one of the x's. (If you swapped one of the h's with another one of the h's, or one of the x's with another one of the x's, it wouldn't make any difference, so you wouldn't have moved to a different solution.) Since h<sub>2</sub> is fixed and x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> are useless for us, what we are actually trying to minimise is w(h<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>) = 2h<sub>1</sub> - (x<sub>3</sub> + x<sub>4</sub>). If h<sub>1</sub> <= x<sub>3</sub> <= x<sub>4</sub>, this is an optimal grouping because no swap can improve the situation. (To see this, let d = x<sub>3</sub> - h<sub>1</sub> and note that w(x<sub>3</sub>, h<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>) - w(h<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>) = 3d which is non-negative, and by symmetry the same argument holds for swapping with x<sub>4</sub>). So that deals with the case n=6.

For n=9, we have 8 jobs that can be moved around, but again, it's useless to move the shortest two. So the formula this time is w(h<sub>1</sub>, h<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>, x<sub>5</sub>, x<sub>6</sub>) = 2h<sub>1</sub> + 2h<sub>2</sub> - (x<sub>3</sub> + x<sub>4</sub> + x<sub>5</sub> + x<sub>6</sub>), but this time we have the constraint that h<sub>2</sub> must not be less than the second-smallest x in the formula (otherwise it couldn't be the highest or joint-highest of any group). As noted before, h<sub>1</sub> and h<sub>2</sub> can't be swapped with each other, so either you swap one of them with an appropriate x (without violating the constraint), or you swap both of them, each with a distinct x. Take h<sub>1</sub> <= x<sub>3</sub> <= x<sub>4</sub> <= h<sub>2</sub> <= x<sub>5</sub> <= x<sub>6</sub>. Again, single swaps can't help, and a double swap can't help either because its effect must necessarily be the sum of the effects of two single swaps. So again, this is an optimal solution.

It looks like this argument is going to work for any n. In which case, finding an optimal solution when you've got an "ideal case" (as defined at the top of my answer) is going to be simple: sort the jobs by quantity and then chop the sorted list into consecutive groups of 3. If this solution proves not to be suitable, you know you haven't got an ideal case.

I will have a think about the non-ideal cases, and update this answer if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem (and I am not sure I do), the solution could be as simple as printing job 1 in all three lanes, then job 2 in all three lanes, then job 3 in all three lanes.

It has a worst case of printing two extra sheets per job.

I can think of cases where this isn't optimal (e.g. three jobs of four sheets each would take six pages rather than four), but it is likely to be far far simpler to develop than a Bin Packing solution (which is NP-complete; each of the three lanes, over time, are representing the bins.)

Comment: Aha, perhaps I was not clear.  One of the requirements would be that as many possible different jobs are in individual lanes.  The reasoning behind this has to do with post-printing efficiency and involves explaining a lot more about the overall process.  (I can do that if anyone wants, but I don't think it necessary.)  I will adjust my post for this.